# Role of where clause in query using exist condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am learning sql at the moment and i come across exist condition. What i know clearly is that and exist checks for the result of the sub query and if the result is TRUE outer query runs and if it is false outer query does not run.
But i am unable to understand is that how where clause fits in all this and how does it relates to outer query.
Please also explains to me what exactly happens after exist condition checks to TRUE.

Comment: Have you tried looking this up? [Top link in google search for "mysql where exists tutorial"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: This is not helping me. Look at one of the example given there
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cities_stores
                WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type);
I know that exist will equal to TRUE but what is the role of "WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type" exactly in all this.

Comment: None the less, you're asking for a very basic description of how `WHERE EXISTS` works. So you definitely haven't made any effort to look this up yourself since google would immediately guide you to hundreds of tutorial on the topic.

Comment: I know very well how `WHERE EXISTS` work but i am not able to understand is if it only gives TRUE and FALSE how does the outer query filter out the result and how does the outer query relates to the `WHERE` clause in the inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how EXISTS relates with the outside query:

```
SELECT *
FROM classes a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM student b
    WHERE b.a_id = a.id  -- Here you relate inner query with outside query
    )
```

You want to get the records in classes where there are at least one record in table students with a foreign key of the id in table classes.

You relate them in the WHERE of the inner query.

If there are no students in that class, the outside query will not return that class.

Comment: `select * from student s1 where not exists ( select * from student s2 where s2.gpa > s1.gpa);`
This is a query to find the student with highest gpa.Please explain how this is working and how `where s2.gpa > s1.gpa` affecting the outer query?

Comment: That is pretty straightforward. In outside query you want all students, but then the NOT EXISTS says that you want only the records where no one has a gpa bigger than the one you have in your outside query. If you have 3 students with 1,2,3 gpa's, for the first two, you will get at least one record in the inner query, making the inner query return TRUE. Since you are doing NOT EXISTS, it translates to false, making the outside query not return the first two students.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand it ,this is looking pretty simple.

Comment: Yes. It is a useful thing to have in your belt :).  If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.